# Unity Spawning way to much objects on collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

im working on an demolition/simulator type game. im working on the basics but my scripts doesnt seem to be working. the idea of the script is, that if the objects encounters an "hard" enough force, it will get replaced by a destroyed version of that object. it works in on small structures. but when the structures get bigger instead of spawning 1 destroyed object, it seems to spawn waaaayy more. and thus the game starts to lag. I think it is becouse some objects hit other objects. when i destroy them by clicking it doesn't happen, only when they hit each other
hope anyone can help.

here's the code

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Destructible : MonoBehaviour { 

    public GameObject debrisPrefab;

    void OnCollisionEnter( Collision collision )
    {
        if (collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > 3f)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Destroy();
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Destroy();
    }

    void Destroy()
    { 
        if (debrisPrefab)
        {         
            Instantiate(debrisPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is a "structure"?

Comment: A couple of destructable blocks together and stacked ontop of eachother

Comment: And each of these blocks has the `Destructible` script component attached to it, right? Why do you change the block to debris even on `OnMouseDown`?

Comment: it can be usefull for if i want to see what happens, and yes all blocks have this script attatched

Comment: The problem is that every time there's a click on the game window, all `Destructible` game objects will turn into a debris. Unless your problem is elsewhere, you should refine your question by explaining in depth what you mean by "when the structures get bigger it seems to spawn way more"

Comment: imma edit the question

Comment: What do i do? Im pretty new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does you `debris` prefab contain other destructible object? Maybe the newly instantiated debris are all destroyed if the spawn and have a collision right away.

Another thing to check is how many elements can trigger the collision. If you have many colliders on your object, onCollisionEnter will be called several times. Also, are you sure you added your script only once to the object?

Finally, if this doesn't help, try using debug lines:

```
Debug.Log(name + " collision enter");
```

to print lines in the console with the name of the colliding object, to try to identify which object causes too many collisions